# CollectionTable Lucene indexing&query

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am opening another thread here about Hibernate Search...

Now I'm dealing with the:

```
@Field
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "product_instance", joinColumns = 
@JoinColumn(name = "doc_uuid"))
@Column(name = "productInstance")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(
        usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE
)
private List<String> productInstanceIds;
```

mapping.

this is how I construct the query:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

        QueryBuilder b = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(DocVersion.class)
                .get();
builder.add(b.keyword().onField(disjMap.get(...)).matching(...)
                        .createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

List results = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(builder.build(), DocVersion.class)
                .getResultList();
```

and query is just fine.

Now my issue is mainy with the `@CollectionTable`. I need to index&query elements out of that 'table'. I know that problem is somewhere in this mapping because, I get 0 results (not the error) when I keep `@Field` annotation in there, but when I remove it I get number of results about  other Entity's props.

So it doesn't scream error but will return nothing. And I mean I use the same query in both scenarios, so it has to be something with that mapping.

So my question is how to make lucene index `@CollectionTable`?

hibernate search: 5.9.3.Final

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to index collections of "atomic" elements (String, integer, enums, ...) in Hibernate Search 5.x, you have two solutions:

1. Rely on the default bridge (the String bridge in your case) and make Hibernate Search apply the bridge multiple types by specifying you don't want the collection indexed, but its elements: add `@IndexedEmbedded` to your collection and you should be good.
2. [Write a custom bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-bridges) that correctly process a List by indexing all of its elements, and reference it in your `@Field` annotation.

Note that once again, you should have a stack trace in your logs that could have tipped you off when you leave the @Field annotation; something like:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.bridge.BridgeException: Exception while calling bridge#set
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```